# schema.org with data scattered over page

Tags: microdata, schema.org

I would like to add schema.org markup to a product page. So basically all of the page is wrapped in a: `<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">`

The page shows the name of the product which I mark with `itemprop="name"`, it shows an image which I mark with `itemprop="image"` etc.

In order to markup the price and the category of the item, I use http://schema.org/Offer. The problem is that price and category are displayed in different parts of the webpage. Is it OK to use `itemtype=http://schema.org/Offer` twice as in the following example?

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
<span itemprop="name">Name of product</span>

<div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
        <span itemprop="category">animals</span>
</div>

<img itemprop="image" src="#"/>

<div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
        <span itemprop="price">1000 EUR</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don’t use [`http://schema.org/Offer`](http://schema.org/Offer) twice. You are creating *two* offers that way.

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19041911/1591669) proposed by user1769790 may work for you, but note that the `image` will be associated with both, the *Product* and the *Offer* (which may or may not be what you want).

You could use the `itemref` attribute instead. See [my answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/52592/17633) on a similar question on Webmasters SE.

It could look like:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemref="foobar-image">

  <span itemprop="name">Name of product</span>

  <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" itemref="foobar-price">
    <span itemprop="category">animals</span>
  </div>

</div>

<img itemprop="image" id="foobar-image" src="" alt="" />

<div itemprop="price" id="foobar-price">1000 EUR</div>
```

Comment: This does seem to work. But what if the price is inside the Product-div (but outside of the Offer-div? In that case google structured data testing tool is telling me that "price" is not part of the product schema.

Comment: @user1583209: Yes, you need to nest them with caution. So in such a case, better don’t use an extensive container, but use `itemref` for all snippets that are scattered. `itemref` can take several `id` values, like `itemref="foo1 foo2 foo3"`.

Comment: Now I made my Product scope to include only the name of the product and an empty span with the Offer scope. All data is defined externally via itemref. Google validates this, however in the search result preview it does not show the price anymore...I suspect because the Product scope is too small and google thinks that the whole page is about something else and only a small part is about the product (which is not true).

Comment: @user1583209: Hm, that’s a pity if Google really interprets it that way. Another alternative could be to duplicate the data: use `meta` for the price in the product container and remove the Microdata on the real price element. Not elegant, though.

Comment: Eventually I went with something like your initial solution. Among others I had to include the product name via an itemref due to the structure of my html document. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check if this answered your Question.

http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=uploaded:8004e75474f6bc632c2a56ed33ba1d90

Enclose Product on the entire page.  img is common for both product and offer.  the solution considers image url for each category (Offer).

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
   <span itemprop="name">Name of product</span>

   <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
      <span itemprop="category">animals</span>


       <img itemprop="image" src="#"/>

       <span itemprop="price">1000 EUR</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can help; if you can add more details of your page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Indeed for this simple case I could put img in Offer type, but for at least two reasons this will not always be possible: 1) If there are other schema types in-between which are not in Offer. 2) If other html code does not allow creation of the Offer-div. So I am still not sure whether it is OK to have two "itemtype Offer" within one Product itemtype and whether these data from these Offer types would be interpreted as belonging to the same physical product.